# How to stop the timer at OnDisconnected event in signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, signalr

I have started a timer when my hub connection is established in `PushNotificationData` method by clients requests.

As per timer interval, it does fetch the records from the db and push to the clients.
but when clients got disconnected ,this timer has to be stopped instead of pulling continuously.

So I have used OnDisconnected event to stop the timer. but unfortunately timer not getting stopped

here is my code:

```
public class NotifyHub : Hub
{
    private string ConnectionId;
    private int UserId;
    private int UserTypeId;

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Enabled = false;
        //logic code removed for brevity
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
    public void PushNotificationData(Int32 userId, Int16 userTypeId)
    {

        UserId = userId;
        UserTypeId = userTypeId;
        ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed1;
        timer.Interval = 6000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();

    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed1(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var notificationParams = new PushNotificationRequest
        {
            FilterProperty = new Common.Filters.FilterProperty { Offset = 0, RecordLimit = 0, OrderBy = "datechecked desc" },
            Filters = new List<Common.Filters.FilterObject> { new Common.Filters.FilterObject { LogicOperator = 0, ConditionOperator = 0, Function = 0, FieldName = "", FieldValue = "", FieldType = 0 } }
        };
        using (INotificationManager iNotifity = new NotificationManager())
        {
            var taskTimer = Task.Run(async () =>
            {                        
                var NotificationResult = iNotifity.GetPushNotificationData(notificationParams, UserId, UserTypeId);
                //Sending the response data to all the clients based on ConnectionId through the client method NotificationToClient()
                Clients.Client(ConnectionId).NotificationToClient(NotificationResult);
                //Delaying by 6 seconds.
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                //}
              });
        }
    } 
}
```

When I debug it, it shows timer `enabled=true`  even after `OnDisconnected` fires.

the moment `OnDisconneted` is executing , i can able to see that timer get updated `enabled=false`. after it come out from the `OnDisconnected` `timer.enabled`got `true` again.

Comment: You need to refactor this design.  Hubs are not meant to retain state.

Answer (score 5):

Read about the Hub Object Lifetime [here](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubclass). The important part is this

> Because instances of the Hub class are transient, you can't use them to maintain state from one method call to the next. Each time the server receives a method call from a client, a new instance of your Hub class processes the message. To maintain state through multiple connections and method calls, use some other method such as a database, or a static variable on the Hub class, or a different class that does not derive from Hub. If you persist data in memory, using a method such as a static variable on the Hub class, the data will be lost when the app domain recycles.

You essentially creating a new timer every time a new Hub is created. So you land up with multiple timers all calling the Timer_Elapsed1 method. You could try making Timer static and keep track of the connection count. That way you could stop the timer when all clients are disconnected. Be aware though that even static variables are vulnerable to be lost if the app domain recycles (as pointed out in the docs above).

Comment: can't create a timer per connection ? So we can stop the timer once the user disconnected . a